# Mega problems with opening and reading text files

Tags: python, file, text

I'm writing a day trading bot and for a compenent I need to save the height(float) of my current trade in a text file. Writing to the file is easy but reading is giving me anuerisms. I've looked through every website related to reading text files and it does not help.

So this code below will do these things:

1. If the txtfile contains anything in it it will always return nothing
2. if I manually place anything in the text file it will read it the first time I run the code but 
   any run after will be blank again, even though the txtfile still has something in it.
3. Using readlines instead of read just returns []

```
f = open('height_shortterm.txt', 'r')
height = f.read()

print(height)
f.close
```

I've been doing pretty advanced python for over 6 months now and this is stressing me out hardcore.

Comment: Where do you run this code? You have to be in the same directory as your `.txt` file since you have a relative path. You must have another copy of this file which is empty.

Comment: Forgot brackets after ```close()```

Comment: You should use `context managers` to deal with files, and yes it's `f.close()`.

Comment: Maybe file under read-write activity? Do you try `with open('height_shortterm.txt', 'rb', encoding='utf-8')`?

Comment: I don't think your file and script are in the same directory. can you please try giving the full path to the text file in your open command?

Comment: opening for reading should really not even necessitate a close (but it certainly doesnt hurt and is a good habit to be in) but my guess is @truncet is dead on the money there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have only given us half of the problem ... at a guess your paths are screwed up and you are not writing or not reading from where you think you are ... you should probably be using absolute paths ...

```
with open("some_file.txt","w") as f:
    f.writelines(["hello","world"])

with open("some_file.txt","r") as f:
    print(f.readlines())
```

Answer (score 0):

1. try to use a context manager `with` so that you wont be having troubles about closing the file, resetting the pointer.
2. `readlines()` returns a list of lines almost like `read().split()` .
3. make sure you close the file in any other application if you are in a windows system.
4. if there is an encoding error, use `encoding='utf-8'` or appropriate one.

see if the following piece of code works :

```
with open('height_shortterm.txt', 'r') as f:
    x= f.readlines()
print(x)
```

Comment: this is equivelent to the OP's code ... other than the context manager (which i can pretty much guarantee is not the issue, although you are correct about it being best practice) all you can really do is provide the write alongside to prove that it works when they are truly the same filepath (my guess is that they are not looking in the same place for the file)

Comment: is there an error trace I am missing?  because as far as I remember if the file is not present it should throw an error(No Such file) while reading, while writing it just creates a new file.

Comment: yeah good point I didnt think that through ... still i suspect the problem is in the code that is not provided